# Compelled and compeled - American English

Tags: american-english, orthography, past-tense, present-participles

As for the British English it's always taught - compel, compe**ll**ed, compe**ll**ing

Some of the books/dictionaries say that in American English you say compel, compe**l**ed, compe**l**ing instead, you simply don't double that l.

Moreover, Merriam Webster (11th Collegiate) doesn't mention "compeled" at all. With counsel - both options are listed.

Interestingly, [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=compeled%3Aeng_us_2012%2Ccompelled%3Aeng_us_2012%2Ccompeled%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Ccompelled%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccompeled%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccompelled%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccompeled%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccompelled%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) doesn't indicate much usage of "compeled". On the [other](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=counseled%3Aeng_us_2012%2Ccounselled%3Aeng_us_2012%2Ccounselled%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Ccounseled%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccounseled%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccounselled%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccounselled%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccounseled%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) hand, "counseled" is more popular than "counselled" in AmE

How is it really in American English?

Comment: The key part of your question is the word "really". You know the dictionary prescriptions; you know the usage statistics; what source do you want one to cite to answer how it *really* is in American English?

Comment: What books say *"compeled"* is acceptable in American English? They are wrong. Rule: in British English, double the 'l'. In American English, double the 'l' if the last syllable is stressed. So *"counseled"*, but *"compelled"*. (This rule isn't as strange as it looks: it's the rule used in both American and British English if the word ends in many other consonants, including 't', 'd', 'p', 'b', 'r', 'm', 'n'.) *Merriam-Webster* probably includes the alternative *counselled* because some people (even Americans) use the British spelling.

Comment: ArmenԾիրունյան: for instance, what native speakers say? Or maybe I know something wrong? 
Peter Shor: Thanks!

Comment: I might have well overinterpreted the rule. I don't remember the exact source.

Comment: @marmistrz: Native speakers *say* /kəmˈpɛld/ :).

Comment: I'm still waiting for you to give examples of 'Some of the books/dictionaries [that] say that in American English you say compel, compeled, compeling instead'. How do we know whether your question has substance? You may be making a false claim (which would render the question unacceptable here). As Araucaria points out, a simple rule does not hold governing the spelling of such words; perhaps you've assumed that there was one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rule of thumb guide for consonant doubling before suffixes is this:

If the last syllable of the root is:

1. stressed
2. ends in: consonant vowel consonant

we usually double the final consonant before the suffix. There are some letters that we don't generally double before suffixes. The most important are 'w' and 'y'. The letter 'l' is *not* one of these letters:

- be'**gin**ning
- '**lag**ging
- in'**fer**ring
- ex'**pel**ling

Above we see four words whose roots have stressed final syllables. As they all have a consonant/vowel/consonant ending, the final consonant is doubled. This also occurs with the verb *expel* in both British and American English.

Note this does not happen with most words if the final syllable is not stressed. In other words if condition (1) is not satisfied:

- 'lis**ten**ing
- 'of**fer**ing
- 'co**lor**ing

In the examples above there is no doubling of the final consonant.

However, traditionally, in British English, but not American, we have a rule for doubling double root final 'l'. If condition (2) above applies, whether the syllable is stressed or not, we double final 'l':

- 'tra**vel**ling
- 'pum**mel**ling
- 'coun**sel**ling

[It should be noted, however, that some American style spelling is now an acceptable alternative for some British words. So you can also find 'pummeling' for example in texts using British English.]

Comment: The 'rule' seems not deserving of the name.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, there's loads of exceptions such as compound words eg: hiccupping etc. Are you thinking of any particular exceptions?

Comment: I'm thinking that 'The rule for consonant doubling before suffixes is this:' needs toning down to 'A rule-of-thumb that often works to predict the occurrence of consonant doubling before suffixes is this:'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth yes, I already had something more like that. Then I started to put in the exceptional rules and then it all got a bit long so I restarted. I'll probably do that - but I'd be interested to know what exceptions you're thinking of?

Comment: You offer a lot of exceptions, or tweakings of rules, yourself. _Focusing_ and _focussing_, _busing_ and _bussing_, _biasing_ and _biassing_, _clarinetist_ and _clarinettist_, _counselor_ and _counsellor_ show that any 'rules' are, at least on occasion, arbitrary.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'd put the rule of thumb in there, but yes, true, there's lot's of potential exceptions! However,as a guide for oneself,  one won't trip up *too* often with the rule of thumb. *Clarinette* or *clarinet* so nothing irregular there ;)

Comment: AHDEL, Collins and RHK Webster's don't license _clarinette_ but all offer the choice between _clarinetist_ and _clarinettist_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, I stand corrected! (What on earth's going on with the pron on AHDEL btw? It's awful!)

Answer (score 4):

You won't find *compeled* in the [American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/), [Webster's New World College Dictionary](http://websters.yourdictionary.com/), or [ODO's US English](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us) corpus, either.

The [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), which samples published texts from 1990–2012, returns zero matches for *compeled* versus 2651 for *compelled*.

For that matter, it also returns zero results for *expeled* (vs. 2057 for *expelled*), zero for *repeled* (425 for *repelled*), and zero for *impeled* (367, *impelled*). There is one result for *propeled*, but that is almost certainly a typographical error, as *propelled* is used in every other instance by the same publication (the San Francisco *Chronicle*), and a total of 1648 times in the corpus.

The Google NGram for these forms suggest the double-*L* version has always predominated in American English, so it is not even a matter of one form losing popularity over time. Either your books are wrong or you have misinterpreted them.